# Entity Framework code first INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 code first with Sqlserver 2008 R2.

Below are my Model classes

```
  public class Ninja
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public bool ServedInOniwaban { get; set; }
        public Clan Clan { get; set; }
        public int ClanId { get; set; }
        public List<NinjaEquipment> EquipmentOwned { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime  DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
    public class NinjaEquipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  ClanName { get; set; }
        public EquipmentType Type { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Ninja Ninja { get; set; }

    }
    public class Clan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClanName { get; set; }
        public List<Ninja> Ninjas { get; set; }

    }
```

And DbContext class as below,

```
 public class NinjaContext: DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Ninja> Ninjas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Clan> Clans{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<NinjaEquipment> Equipment { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Program class,

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertNinja();
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        private static void InsertNinja()
        {
            var ninja = new Ninja
            {
                Name = "JulieSan",
                ServedInOniwaban = false,
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980,1,1),
                ClanId = 1,
            };
            using (var context= new NinjaContext())
            {
                context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
                context.Ninjas.Add(ninja);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
```

Before running the code I have inserted values in Clan table.
Clan table has one row present as below 
1, 'ClanName'.
Now , while running the code in my program class I am trying to insert row in table called Ninja, as Ninja table has foreign key as ClanId , I am providing clanId as 1 , So it should not throw Foreign key constraint.

> When I tried to run this program I got below error, {"The INSERT
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Ninjas_dbo.Clans_ClanId\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"NinjaDomain.DataModel.NinjaContext\", table \"dbo.Clans\", column
>   'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

On other hand when I tried running below sql script against db I am able run it successfully,

```
INSERT [dbo].[Ninjas]([Name], [ServedInOniwaban], [ClanId], [DateOfBirth])
VALUES ('JulieSan', 'False', '1', '01-01-1980 00:00:00' )
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Ninjas]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to add a Ninja with a ClanId of 1, but there is no Clan with the Id of 1, so the foreign key constraint is violated

Comment: Could you try to reload `Clan` from the database before inserting the `Ninja`?  `ninja.Clan = db.Clans.Find(1);` Will it load successfully for you?

Comment: Actually, I’ve just tried to create a sample project and everything you mentioned works correct for me. `Ninja` is being inserted correct as well as `Clan`.  Please pay attention that your `Id` may be generated by the database so the `Id` of your `Clan` can be not equal to `1`. Make sure you have a `Clan` inside your table and it’s `Id` equals to `1`. I’m not sure what else I could suggest as your issue doesn’t reproduce on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was issue with th db server name. I was using db with Name : (localdb)\mssqllocaldb in EF adapters So all db schema was created in EF adapter project. Then I have added Console application and installed EF in that presentation project.After adding EF in presentation project (Console App) it by default created App.Config, SO  I have removed app.config from EF Adapter project. 
So app.config of console app was pointing to .\SqlExpress db instead of (localdb)\mssqllocaldb. 
My bad.